# How to grab drop-down menu index value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a basic calculator where the the math will carry out based on the operator that is selected from the drop down menu but it isn't working. I'm unsure why it isn't working. I am trying to receive the index of the option selected not the actual text.

My code:

```
var numOne = document.getElementById("num-one");
var numTwo = document.getElementById("num-two");
var menu = document.getElementbyId("menuType"); // feeling like the error is here
var selection = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].value; // or here
var userAnswer = document.getElementById("user-Answer");


numOne.addEventListener("input", math);
numTwo.addEventListener("input", math);

function math() {

    var one = parseFloat(numOne.value) || 0;
    var two = parseFloat(numTwo.value) || 0;
    var userSelect = selection

    if (userSelection == 1){
    userAnswer.innerHTML = one + two;
}
        else if (userSelection == 2){
                userAnswer.innerHTML = one - two;
            }

            else else if (userSelection == 3){
                    userAnswer.innerHTML = one * two;
            }

                else else else if (userSelection == 2){
                        if (two == 0){
                            alert("Error, cannot divide by 0");
                        }
                        else
                        userAnswer.innerHTML = one / two;
            }


}
```

Comment: `menu.selectedIndex` has the index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectedIndex` to return the index of the selected option in a drop-down list.

For example: `document.getElementById("numOne").selectedIndex = "1";`